# How to display data using DataTable with JSON source?

Tags: json, ajax, datatable

I have a JSON data from database. It stored in a hidden textarea. I'd like to use DataTable to display it. This is my current script:

```
$("#btn_find").on('click',function(e){ 
    $('#hidden_textarea').val("");  

    if(is_error > 0){              //This is just an error checking. I skip this part
        alert("There are errors");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        $('.modal').show();
        $('#table_display tbody').remove();
        $('#DataTables_Table_0').empty();
        $('#table_display').DataTable().destroy();

        var par_sent = "some_value";

        $.ajax({
            type     : "POST",
            url      : "<?php echo site_url('Memo/get_memo_by_par'); ?>",           
            dataType : "JSON",
            data     : par_sent,
            success  : function(response){

                if(Object.keys(response).length == 0){
                    alert("There are no data");

                    $('.modal').hide();
                    $('#table_display tbody').remove();
                    $('#DataTables_Table_0').empty();
                    $('#table_display').DataTable().destroy();

                    return false;
                }
                else{

                    $('#hidden_textarea').val(JSON.stringify(response));                    

                    var table = $('.dataTables-example').DataTable({
                                    pageLength  : 15,
                                    responsive  : true,
                                    retrieve    : true,
                                    dom         : '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
                                    ajax        : function (data, callback, settings){

                                        var jdata   = JSON.parse($('#hidden_textarea').val());
                                        var data    = [];
                                        var i       = 1;

                                        jdata.map((d) => {
                                                            var returned = [i++]
                                                            var values   = Object.values(d)

                                                            returned.push(...values)
                                                            data.push(returned)     

                                        })

                                        setTimeout(function() {                                                 
                                            callback({
                                                    draw            : data.draw,
                                                    data            : data,
                                                    recordsTotal    : data.length,
                                                    recordsFiltered : data.length
                                            });                                                 
                                        }, 50);
                                    },
                                    buttons     : [ {extend: 'copy'},
                                                    {extend: 'csv', title: "Report"},
                                                    {extend: 'excel', title: "Report",},
                                                    {extend: 'pdf', title: "Report"},
                                                    {extend: 'print',
                                                        customize: function (win){
                                                            $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                                                            $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');
                                                            $(win.document.body).find('table').addClass('compact').css('font-size', 'inherit');
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                    ]                                   
                                });                         
                } //END ELSE                
            },
            complete: function() {

                $('#table_display').on('draw.dt', function(){

                    $("#table_display tbody tr").each(function(c){                      
                        //COLUMN 1
                        $(this).find('td:eq(0)').css('text-align','right');
                        $(this).find('td:eq(0)').css('width','1%');                         
                    });                 
                });

                $('.modal').hide();
            }
        }); 

    }
});
```

Above script **is working** but for one search only.  I have to reload the page to re-use the feature. The loading modal is keep spinning if I use the search twice. But, the hidden textarea is filled with the correct data.

So, how do I fix my code so it is able to search infintely without refresh the page?

Any script modification to enhance it is allowed. If there are any question or request more example, you can post it in a comment.

Comment: The code looks like it is "obfuscated" deliberately